# Meaning of - "//= require angular/angular"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, integration, require

I have a similar problem of using Angular with Grails, pls. refer this question that already gives all the details/solutions/answers: [How to integrate angular js into grails 2.3.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401951/how-to-integrate-angular-js-into-grails-2-3-4?answertab=votes#tab-top)

In the answers to this question, people have given good answers, but they are talking about ....

*"require the module on screen"*

... & sample code (?) fragments like these:

```
//= require angular/angular.js
//= require_tree views
//= require_self
```

What is the meaning of "requiring" the module ("resource bundles": as given in the first answer), & other/above code fragments, or whatever they are.

Does it means normal require statements:

```
require(['angular']);
```

etc.?

Things are not very clear.

Comment: I am an experienced developer & business professional, with 10 yrs. in systems software, 5 yrs. in business & innovation; & I am new to Web-Development.

Answer (score 3):

In a Ruby on Rails application you would use manifest files to include all your dependencies. That is a code snippet from the application.js (default) manifest file where it's including javascript files or paths using the "//=" javascript include syntax.

Comment: More details here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Answer (score 1):

Grails uses different resource mangement plugins for javascript files, css, images, etc.. Code you mentioned

```
//= require angular/angular.js
//= require_tree views
//= require_self
```

is from [grails asset-pipeline plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline).

Resource bundles term used in [grails resources plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) where you declare bundles in ApplicationResource.groovy file.

When you want set of js or css file to be included in a page you just need to include manifest file (for assest pipeline) or require module (for resources).

Both plugin have good documentation to refer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//= require angular/angular.js
```

Is simply rails syntax for requiring and registering dependencies to your rails applications. Although your question is a little vague if you are trying "require an angular module" than you must list it as a dependency when you declare your angular module. This is totally unrelated to rails but will look something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngTouch',])
```

where the items inside the array (ngRoute, ngTouch) are other modules that become depencies of 'myApp'.

[This](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) page should help!