# groovy server pages is still a good technology?

Tags: grails, spring-boot, gsp

I am evaluating various web frameworks for a new web application we are building. We are trying to compare Grails with Springboot. So, in that context, Grails uses gsp files (Groovy server pages), and I am just wondering if it is still used by others these days? I used to work on jsp in the past, which is pretty much dead. Looks like the general approach these days is to get json or some format response and use some client side javascript libraries like AngularJS to manage your view? Is this correct? Just want to see if there are any opinions or suggestions on this topic? Thanks.

Comment: arent those orthogonal problems? if you do a SPA you still want to generate HTML (e.g. initial request, SEO, non-SPA content, ...)

Comment: In my company we use gsp to create MVP, it's one of the best way in start-ups and demonstrate product. Parallel we works with client version which use API from our grails project.

Answer (score 3):

This fairly depends upon your business logic and complexity of website.

If you want to follow microservices architecture you go for a rest-api and then an angular app which will accept json and process it back and forth to api and to front end.

gsps are close to grails and in grails use sitemesh for templating. If you are sure that you want to keep V with your rest MC part then go for gsp.

Though angular has nothing to do with gsp and hence angular could still be used with using gsp pages. Though you might face some initial problems in integration. Also, angular is a heavy and hence good for single page applications but not for multipage applications.

I would recommend some R n D before making a choice of these technologies.

Following links could help you though:
[How to integrate angular js into grails 2.3.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401951/how-to-integrate-angular-js-into-grails-2-3-4)

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/grails-with-angularjs/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. My app doesn't have too much natively. It gets the information it needs from API calls to other processes (some JSON, some other proprietary format). Is it easy to integrate Angular with gsp?

Comment: See my edit above with links for integrating angular and gsp.